# Dart: Await function call is not waiting and returning Future object

Tags: flutter, dart

I am completely new to Dart and Flutter Development, I understand Async...Await of Javascript but unable to get the similar results in Dart.

Below is a simplified version of a Database Driven Application:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyTestActivity extends StatelessWidget {
  Future<int> testFunction() async {
    // Code returning Integer value from Await function Call
    return 20;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('TEST'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
            child: Text(testFunction().toString()),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Below is the result of the above Widget:
[image]

I would want value 20 over there.

Comment: I see you are using same padding for top-bottom, and left-right.
Instead on only you can use `EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 5)`.
A much handier way to symmetrically pad widgets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Future** in dart is like the **Promise** of javascript.
It'll return the value when it's resolved (or throw error when rejected).
And since you're dealing with a *Promise* (Future) here the return value of *testFunction* (if you don't await it) will be a *Promise* (Future).
I would recommend if you're using Futures in your Widget tree, look into the *FutureBuilder* Widget which let's you better handle Futures in Widget tree.
Restructure your app like this for now.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Test',
        home: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('TEST'),
          ),
          body: Container(
            margin:
                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
            child: FutureBuilder (
                 future: testFunction,
                 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot, ) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                         return Text (snapshot.data.toString());
                     }
                     return CircularProgressIndicator();
                  }
              ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

Comment: Worked for me, Thank you @Saud but there are some changes in the code that you have added in the Answer...

Answer (score 1):

Answer given by Saud worked for me but the code in his Answer has some issues, I am adding the code that worked for me:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    title: 'Test',
    home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('TEST'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        margin:
            const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 5, right: 5),
        child: FutureBuilder<int>(
            future: testFunction(),// Even on Flutter website it's without parentheses but did not work.
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<int> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
              }
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }),
      ),
    ));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you copied pasted and forgot to add @override in my answer?